# Binding a table valued parameter containing a VARCHAR(MAX) column

Tags: c++, sql-server, visual-c++, odbc

I have successfully bound parameters and executed queries with table valued parameters containing columns of integral and floating point numbers. But when I try to bind a char array containing null terminated strings in equally sized blocks I keep getting the error "String data, right truncation".

Has anyone done this before? What am I supposed to do differently when binding text arrays to a TVP column?

Comment: Can you show the code, so we're not guessing exactly how you are "trying to bind a char array"?

Comment: Include the SQL STATE that is returned with this message as well.  You can get that message in more than one way and the SQL STATE offers an explanation of which case you are hitting.  If you are binding a parameter for insert check 1) that the size of your data is not larger than the column in the table and 2) that the value for the ColumnSize argument to SQLBindParameter is correct.  Note that this is not always just a count of characters.  If each character is 2 bites long, ColumnSize will be (2*#ofcharacters)+1.  Likewise, the characters are 3 bytles long you multiple by 3.